# Girsanov theorem and system equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, systems-of-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Hey I need to use the Girsanov theorem to solve system of equations:

$dX_1(t)=X_2(t)dt+dW(t)$

$dX_2(t)=(X_1(t)-1)dt$

How to do it?

Comment: Can anyone help? I have no idea how to apply Girsanov theorem to solve this